# how to know when a worker panic in golang ants

Tags: go, goroutine, panic

I am using [ants](https://github.com/panjf2000/ants) as my goroutine pool in my program. This library handles panics of workers [itself](https://github.com/panjf2000/ants/blob/master/worker.go#L52) and won't propagate the panic, but I want to catch the panic whenever it occurs in one of my workers.

Is there any way to do this using `ants` or is there any other library to replace it with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I investigated more, I realized that I can define and use [my own panic handler](https://github.com/panjf2000/ants/blob/master/options.go#L45). It should be passed to the `New` function when you are creating an `ants` pool.